# Setting text field as first responder on app launch in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a simple app with a couple text entry fields. When I launch the app, nothing happens until I tap a field or use a control. How do I set the focus to be on the first text field and open the keyboard when the app launches, saving the user a tap? (new to swift - is this setting the first responder? - not sure how that works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with @Sh_Khan's answer,

Just verify one more thing to disable the hardware keyboard. You'll need to toggle your keyboard through `⌘K` or through below steps,

- iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard
- Uncheck `Connect Hardware Keyboard`

Comment: yes, sometimes this occurs with simulators

Comment: Agreed @Sh_Khan

Comment: Thank you both, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` do

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTexF:UITextField!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
    firstTexF.becomeFirstResponder()  
}
```

Comment: Right answer, just a minor styling comment - you can (and it's preferable to) omit the ```self``` and simply access ```firstTexF``` directly.